# About the failure of the JWT interceptor?

Tags: java, interceptor

I had a problem with the actual development

My project is a front - end separation project. There was a problem when testing JWT validation with the postman, and my token was placed in the request header.

Some problems with the interceptor were found during the test, and if my request had a token value it would intercept the request.
The interceptor fails if the token attribute is not present in the request header.

I was the backend port of the direct call in the test

I have tried to change WebMvcConfigurer WebMvcConfigurationSupport WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, these three. My spring-boot version is 1.5

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
registry.addInterceptor(jwtInterceptor)
.addPathPatterns("/df/**")
.addPathPatterns("/sd/**")
.addPathPatterns("/as/**");
}
```

I want my interceptor to intercept it regardless of whether the token attribute is present in the request
Does anyone have this problem or know how to solve it?